# Specify parent page template

Tags: pages, page-template

I don't want to define a template from admin because I have lot of page and so if I change it I might forget my selected template.

So I want make that template in page.

Here is my page structure

> Mango  (page)
>
> -Orange (parent page)
>
> -- lime (parent page)

For my mango and all parent pages I will use the same template, but I don't want to that by selecting one for each from admin. I want that defined in functions.php or page.php with `get_template_part` or any other way. For example, if lime/mango/orange or whatever which is under `mango` page, then `get_template_part` will use `mango` so that my template will be mango.php.

Any suggestions to make this work?

i am not sure is that make scene or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All types of templates have [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy) to let you control what template is loaded. For pages there's `page_template`, where you can check [the queried page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) against an ID, or see if the ID exists in [an array of a page's ancestor IDs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors).

```
function wpd_page_template_filter( $template ){
    // the ID of Mango page
    $parent_page = 20;

    if( $parent_page == get_queried_object_id()
        || in_array( $parent_page, get_ancestors( get_queried_object_id(), 'page' ) ) ){
        $template = locate_template( 'mango.php', false );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpd_page_template_filter' );
```

Comment: yes this what i want.. it work. thanks .. thank you so much